# After a Flutter upgrade, I am getting the error "Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'"

Tags: flutter, dart, runtime, flutter-upgrade

When I upgraded Flutter from Flutter 2.10.2 to a newer version, I got this error on every Flutter project I had created. Even when I created the new Flutter project (the simple counter app) when I am going to run the app, I am getting this error.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-bd539267b42051b0da3d16ffa8f48949dce8aa8f. Required by: project :app
> Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-bd539267b42051b0da3d16ffa8f48949dce8aa8f.
> Could not parse POM https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-bd539267b42051b0da3d16ffa8f48949dce8aa8f/x86_debug-1.0.0-bd539267b42051b0da3d16ffa8f48949dce8aa8f.pom
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not running on stable channel, try switching to stable and run an upgrade.

```
flutter channel stable && flutter upgrade
```

Then download the project dependencies and run the app again.

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run
```